# Lining up two layers in Illustrator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, illustrator, spatial-adjustment

We have an adobe illustrator file with nice base map from ArcMap that has a layer that we made edits to.  It is our town local streets with some additions and some subtractions.

we export the streets from ArcMap to .ai and it does not line up, apparently above file was rotated a bit and stretched, transformed or skewed etc. I can get it close, but so not perfect at all.

Is there any hope to line up our modified .ai layer to the original layer in the above file so it lines up perfectly?

We want to do this because the first .ai file has nice base maps etc, and just the one layer is changed.  WE also don't have access to the original ArcMap.

Comment: This link may be helpful, [Exporting ArcGIS to Illustrator - Problems with images becoming strips or non-usable layers](http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showtopic=9794)

Answer (score 1):

For you to be able to do this in Illustrator will need that software to be able to support spatial adjustment (rubbersheeting).

To do this in Illustrator (which I do not use) it looks like you may need [MAPublisher](http://www.avenza.com/forum/index.php?topic=457.0).